# Read binary file as byte[] and send from servlet as char[]

Tags: java

I have a servlet which reads BINARY file and sends it to a client.

```
byte[] binaryData = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(path);
response.getWriter().print(new String(binaryData));
```

It works for NON BINARY files. When I have a BINARY file, I get `receive file length bigger than origin or received file not the same`. How I can read and send binary data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Not* via the `Writer`. Writers are for *text* data, not binary data. Your current code is trying to interpret arbitrary binary data as text, using the system default encoding. That's a really bad idea.

You want an output stream - so use `response.getOutputStream()`, and write the *binary* data to that:

```
response.getOutputStream().write(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(path));
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not use Writer, it will add encoding of your characters and there will not always be a 1:1 mapping (as you have experienced). Instead use the OutputStream directly.

And avoid reading the full content if you don't need it available at once. Serving many parallel requests will quickly consume memory. FileUtils have methods for this.

```
FileUtils.copyFile(path, response.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: This is answer for my second question, about automatic adding charset in headers. Thanks!